# Post image on Facebook web

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

In my app, I am using SLComposeViewController to post images on Facebook app, which works fine. Requirement is, if the Facebook app is not installed, I would like to open the web page and allow user to post the image though web. Please anyone can advise how to post the image on Facebook web? I have iOS 9 and above with Xcode 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

Use Facebook SDK for post image to facebook. You can find code and documentation here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios

Facebook SDK will handle all types of exception and scenario.

Answer (score 0):

If Facebook app is not installed. but you FB accounts synced with setting app in your iPhone. 
you can use below code to share the photo. But it will not open web browser.

```
FBSDKSharePhoto *photo = [[FBSDKSharePhoto alloc] init];
photo.image = img; // your image
FBSDKSharePhotoContent *content = [[FBSDKSharePhotoContent alloc] init];
content.photos = @[photo];
[FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self
                                         withContent:content
                                            delegate:self];
```

To share via web browser, you can use below code.

```
 FBSDKShareLinkContent *content  = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
 content.imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:img]; // image url
[FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self.viewController
                                         withContent:content
                                            delegate:self];
```